# Make matplotlib annotation visible on point event

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I have created annotations for each point on a graph using matplotlib. In the original instance of creating the annotations I have set them to "visible=False". On clicking the point, I would like it so that the annotation became visible. Is this possible, and how?

Thanks

Comment: First off, as a shameless plug, have a look at `mpldatacursor` https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor  It does exactly what you want. However, in general, you'd just want to connect a callback function to the pick event that does something like `annotations[event.artist].set_visible(True)` and redraws.  I don't have time to give a full example right now, but see http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html

Comment: @JoeKington I read the question headline and clicked with the intention of plugging `mpldatacursor` ;)